# Xamarin studio fails to open F# files

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin-studio

I've just installed Xamarin studio to try out the F# experience on OSX. The install works fine and I'm able to create the F# tutorial project, but when it tries to open the Tutorial.fs file I get the following message:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.ResourceXmlProvider.Open'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/TypeExtensionNode.cs:93 
  at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SyntaxModeCodon.get_SyntaxMode () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SyntaxModeCodon.cs:42 
  at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SyntaxModeService+<SyntaxModeService>c__AnonStorey17.<>m__61 (Mono.TextEditor.TextDocument d) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SyntaxModeService.cs:45 
  at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.SyntaxModeProvider.Create (Mono.TextEditor.TextDocument doc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/SyntaxMode.cs:839 
  at Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting.SyntaxModeService.GetSyntaxMode (Mono.TextEditor.TextDocument doc, System.String mimeType) [0x00036] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Highlighting/SyntaxModeService.cs:157 
  at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.UpdateMimeType (System.String fileName) [0x00042] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorView.cs:926 
  at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.Load (System.String fileName, System.Text.Encoding loadEncoding) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorView.cs:792 
  at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.Load (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor/SourceEditorView.cs:729 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.LoadFileWrapper.Invoke (System.String fileName) [0x00107] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/Workbench.cs:1181
```

Double clicking on the file also results in the above message. The file is visible in Xamarin studio. I can run the tutorial project and it opens up a terminal and executes the file, if I'm using mono 3.0.10. I'm using the xamarin studio version 4.0.4 and have both mono 3.0.10 and 2.10.12 installed.

There is one more thing that I don't understand that might be related and that is under references I have a warning that FSharp.Core is not available for Mono / .NET 4.0 (in mono 3.0.10). I thought that would stop me from running the file but it wasn't that's why I'm not sure if it is related or not.

Comment: You'll find up-to-date F# + Xamarin Studio installation instructions at http://fsharp.org/use/ios/.  (The instructions apply for Android as well)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to use the latest version of the F# binding as that error was a breaking change between version 4.0.1 and 4.0.3 of Xamarin Studio.

You dont specify what version you are currently using but if you use latest version from either the addin channel or manually: [F# binding 3.2.15](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Stable/Mac/4.0.3/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding-3.2.15.mpack) everything should be working ok.

The FSharp.Core issue you mentioned is also a [known issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/30).

Comment: I installed everything today, including the bindings which I added as an addin so I think I have the latest version of the bindings.

Comment: So are you using 3.2.15 of the F# binding?  
Xamarin Studion | Addin Manager | Language bindings will show you the installed version.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to get back on that later. I am at work now and haven't my macbook with me, but I'll try later today. How do I install the latest version if I haven't the latest installed? I used the Addin Manager today to install it and thought it would give me the latest, is there an alternative way to install the bindings if it is not the latest?

Comment: Im guessing you will be using version 3.2.14.  

I think there may be a bug in Xamarin's Addin manager not picking up 3.2.15 from the channel.  You can update manually by clicking on the link above to the mpack file.  There is an `Install from file` option in the Add in manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, and couldn't solve it until I upgraded to the alpha version 3.3 with the latest upgrades.